# ReactJS getting results from a Promise

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-saga

In my sagas, I am sending user credentials to the backend

```
const request = client.post('api/JwtAuth/GenerateToken', {UserName: action.username, Password: action.password})
console.log(request)
```

client looks like this

import axios from "axios"

```
const client = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'https://localhost:5001/',
    timeout: 600000000000,
    headers: {
        ContentType: 'application/json'
    }
})

export default client
```

[image: Chrome Browser console]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
  const request = client.post('api/JwtAuth/GenerateToken', {UserName: 
    action.username, Password: action.password})

  request.then(response => {
    // the response body can be accessed through the "data" property
    console.log(response.data)
  })
  console.log(request)
```

UPDATE:

You are doing this inside a saga, right?
If so, the best way to get the request response data is to use the `call` effect. Import it from `redux-saga/effects`, and get the response like this:

```js
  const response = yield call(
    client.post,
    'api/JwtAuth/GenerateToken',
    { UserName: action.username, Password: action.password }
  )

  console.log(response.data)
```

Answer (score 2):

what is your question? If the question why are you seeing Promise on the console? That's because you are dealing with promises, either use .then

```
client.post().then(res => console.log(res.data)).catch(err => console.log(err))
```

or async await syntax

```
await client.post()
```

Comment: I've always used await but my function doesn;t like it since I declared it like
function *fetchUser(action)

Comment: uh, than using Promise.then() would work in your case

Comment: Do I need to do everything inline? It seems like I am adding logic into my .then() statement like extracting values from data to a variable then managing exceptions if data is null/undefined.

Comment: No, not necessary. the `.then(res => {})` statement is used to handle the case when/if the promise is Resolved. Usually, in a frontend application you use the `res` parameter to update the state or render something new to the UI. You use the catch to handle errors. If you are worried about the style of your code you can write  `.then()` and `.catch()` on new lines like this: https://dcv19h61vib2d.cloudfront.net/thumbs/scikit-learn-create-a-resolved-promise-with-promise-resolve-SyvleFewQ/scikit-learn-create-a-resolved-promise-with-promise-resolve-SyvleFewQ.jpg